# how can I POST cookies to a different link?

Tags: javascript, cookies, cross-domain

Is there any way to POST all the cookies(cookie name , value and expire time)  available for a specific domain (e.g .example.com) using javascript  ? . I own the domain that I need the cookies to POST from but I want to post them to a different domain (e.g example2.com). After the cookies are POST ed I also need to redirect the client to a specific link so I think some ajax may be required

#### Note :  I do not need to read/write cookies on different domain. I simply need to send/transport the cookies names/values/exp of the current domain to a different domain as HTTP POST values

Comment: Do you own both domains? and how much control do you have over the second one?

Comment: I control the both domain names . On the first domain I can use only html/javascript/css , on the 2nd domain I can use anything including server-side programming (shell, php etc )

Comment: interesting - I faced a similar problem with even less control recently. I found this, http://jectbd.com/?p=611 . Let me know if it helps and you want me to make it an answer . it seems like you want to use POST.

Comment: ... I'm afraid to answer with it because it's "hacky" and I fear it would get downvoted -- a lot. Lol.

Comment: I don't find it hacky, I find it useful

Comment: Someone is performing a XSS attack, eh?

Answer (score 2):

You can access the cookies using `document.cookie`. However, this only gives you the name and value - there's no way (that I know of) to get the expiration date of a cookie. It contains a string with all the cookies, in a `name1=value1; name2=value2; name3=value3;` format.

Sending it as a POST request to another domain can be done with [cross-domain XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_Access_Control), but if you don't need to read the HTTP response of the request, submitting a form should be enough. Simply create an invisible `<form>` with its method attribute set to "post", the action attribute set to the URL on the other domain and the target attribute set to the id of an invisible iframe, add the cookies as an `<input>`, and submit the form.

```
<iframe id="foo" style="display: none"></iframe>
<form id="bar" method="post" target="foo"
      action="http://www.someotherdomain.com/handle_cookies.php">
    <input id="cookies" type="hidden" name="cookies" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('cookies').value = document.cookie;
    document.getElementById('bar').submit();
</script>
```

Its probably better to create the `<iframe>` and `<form>` dynamically, using JavaScript, instead of having it written in the HTML, but I'm too lazy to write that at 2:30AM, sorry :P

**note**: If the first domain is accessed on SSL, **make sure** the connection to the other domain is also over SSL, otherwise you'll be transmitting secured cookies over HTTP as plain text. You can remove the scheme part from the URL of the other domain (e.g. `//www.someotherdomain.com/handle_cookies.php` instead of `http://www.someotherdomain.com/handle_cookies.php`), making it use the same scheme as the one used where the cookies are sent from. I highly recommend doing that.

Comment: the domains are not using SSL but unfortunately the script just doesn't work . I mean that it doesn't do anything when I access the page (I'm checking with a http analyzer)

Comment: Define "not working"? Are there any errors? Is the post request being sent, but without the cookies? what?

Comment: No request is made. I also tried to modify the form /convert it to javascript but still no success

Comment: foo = document.createElement("IFRAME"); 
   foo.style ="display: none"; 
   document.body.appendChild(foo); 
var submitForm = document.createElement("FORM");
 document.body.appendChild(submitForm);
 submitForm.method = "POST";

    document.getElementById('cookies').value = document.cookie;
    document.getElementById('bar').submit();

Answer (score 0):

The link describes a method that comes close to the requirement. But it uses the `window.name` property instead of `cookies` to send data.

Google cache copy, because the original link seized to work for a while.

[Using window.name transport for cross-site POST scripting](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3akqxCaheZiHoJ%3ajectbd.com/?p=611%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&source=encrypted.google.com)

Answer (score -1):

I think due to security reasons you can't read/write a cookie for a different domain. You can apply a specific path for the cookie to be available to such as a specific folder outside of your root. I think the way the browsers work is they find cookies for the site they are accessing at the moment, and use them accordingly. But allowing for cookies to be cross domains would open up to many threats. I think, if you really want though I can't promise something like this working fully.

If you build a script on the other domain that will write a cookie based on a trigger and then you use something like PHP cURL to bring the page into the domain your working with at the moment you may be able to invoke a cookie from the other domain. This is pure theory though not something I have tested. The idea is since you own both domains its assumed you also have access to both hosting servers. So with that you need something on both ends to work with one another to do what you want, rather then hope for a one sided solution.

Reference: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: Yes I'm thinking to use cURL to handle the cookie received on the other domain but I'm not very familiar with client-side technologies so I small code snippet which should extract the cookies(names, values and expiration time) create a form  and POST them to the other domain would help me a lot ! I do not need to write cookies on the other domain. I simply need to send cookies names/values/exp of the current domain to a different domain as HTTP POST values

Comment: Well with that, if you are already using PHP you could get the PHP to set/unset and read any cookie data. Breaking it down accordingly then feed it to the other site through that. JavaScript doesn't have a native way of setting/getting cookies like php does where you just type setcookie or $_COOKIE[]. But there is means of doing it with JavaScript none the less http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp tells you how.

Comment: I need a solution how to do it with javascript. The question is quite clear "using javascript".